# Carrierwave + fog + S3 +Rails Cannot save full URL in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I am trying to save the full url of the image uploaded with carrierwave in my database, not just the identifier. I have the image URL available before saving it, however upon save only the identifier appears in the database. I have the host and endpoint set in the Carrierwave.rb config, as well as the asset_host. See below:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'                        # required
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:              'AWS',                        # required
    aws_access_key_id:     'xxx',                        # required
    aws_secret_access_key: 'yyy',                        # required
    region:                'eu-west-1',                  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
    host:                  's3.example.com',             # optional, defaults to nil
    endpoint:              'https://s3.example.com:8080' # optional, defaults to nil
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'name_of_directory'                          # required
  config.fog_public     = true                                        # optional, defaults to true
config.asset_host = "https://s3.example.com:8080/name_of_directory"
end
```

The asset_host does not seem to be doing much in this case. Is there another way to make sure the full url is being saved?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Storing all the full urls could lead to a lot of duplication (as the host would be the same for all of them). As such, the approach here is to just store the part that is different and build the URL from the known host and stored identifier. So when you load the file you should be able to find the url readily using the carrierwave interface (and it should respect the asset_host if supplied).

Is there a particular reason you need it to store the full urls here?

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. While I understand the reasoning behind the functionality, from a database standpoint I do not want to be reliant on Carrierwave for all interactions, and maintain the flexibility and freedom to use other solutions in the future, as well as interact with the database directly, or import/export data as needed. Do you have a solution to this problem? Thank you in advance

Comment: Fair enough. I'm less familiar with the specifics here (more familiar with fog itself than carrierwaves broader issues). I think you could probably do something like:

```
before_save do
  self.full_url = self.url
end
```

And ensure full_url is a defined column (and perhaps even creating url as a column would be sufficient, I don't use rails much either). Anyway, I think setting a value for a column from the method at save time would probably get you what you want.